# What permission are required on the source to copy a SQL Azure database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I need to grant permissions to a remote development team so they can copy schema changes on a database to their local dev instances. I see many posts similar to this, but they seem to focus on what is required in the destination server, rather than rights to read everything necessary on the source.

Currently, the user is in the db_datareader role and while they seem to be able to read a good portion of the table structure, configuration items such as defaults seems to be obscured, and stored proc and view definitions don't seem to be available, either.

I need the team to be able to copy from our Test/UAT instance, but I don't want them to be able to modify it. They should already have sa access to their local dev instances.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to grant permissions to a remote development team so they can copy schema changes on a database to their local dev instances.

I think you can using [Azure SQL database Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data).

Data Sync is useful in cases where data needs to be kept up-to-date across several Azure SQL databases or SQL Server databases. Here are the main use cases for Data Sync:

- **Hybrid Data Synchronization**: With Data Sync, you can keep data
  synchronized between your on-premises databases and Azure SQL
  databases to enable hybrid applications. This capability may appeal
  to customers who are considering moving to the cloud and would like
  to put some of their application in Azure.
- **Distributed Applications**: In many cases, it's beneficial to separate
  different workloads across different databases. For example, if you
  have a large production database, but you also need to run a
  reporting or analytics workload on this data, it's helpful to have a
  second database for this additional workload. This approach minimizes
  the performance impact on your production workload. You can use Data
  Sync to keep these two databases synchronized.
- **Globally Distributed Applications**: Many businesses span several
  regions and even several countries/regions. To minimize network
  latency, it's best to have your data in a region close to you. With
  Data Sync, you can easily keep databases in regions around the world
  synchronized.

Data Sync is based around the concept of a Sync Group. A Sync Group is a group of databases that you want to synchronize.

A Sync Group has the following properties:

- The **Sync Schema** describes which data is being synchronized.
- The **Sync Direction** can be bi-directional or can flow in only one
  direction. That is, the Sync Direction can be Hub to Member, or
  Member to Hub, or both.
- The **Sync Interval** describes how often synchronization occurs.
- The **Conflict Resolution Policy** is a group level policy, which can be
  Hub wins or Member wins.

For more detail, please see [Overview of SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#overview-of-sql-data-sync).

With Data sync, you can set your Azure SQL database as **Hub database**, teams local dev instances as **member database**, set **Sync Direction** to 'Hub to Member'.

Then you can sync the schema changes on a database to their local dev instances manually or automatically. Reference: [Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was unaware of that tool, so thanks. But it appears to be more focused on data, than the structure of the DB, itself. All I actually needed to do was to grant VIEW DEFINITION and that gave me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION was what I needed.

Not sure how I didn't stumble on that in my searches, but there it is.